# How can I make my DIV clear?

Tags: css, css-float

I have the following code:

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div style="float: left; padding-right: 1%;">
    <label class="adm">Created</label>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; padding-right: 1%;">
    <label class="adm">Created</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mdl_ftr"></div>

.clearfix:after{
  clear: both;
  bdy: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.mdl_ftr {
    min-height: 69px;
}
.mdl_ftr {
    background: Red;
    min-height: 45px;
}
```

and an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63gkw/)

I would like the background color of mdl_ftr to start AFTER the labels. Is there a simple way that I can make this happen. Right now the mdl_ftr DIV starts right at the top left corner of the first label. What I want is it to follow the labels and not appear as a background to them.

Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It is common, when using floating elements, to have another element to clear content in the layout. Something like :

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div style="float: left; padding-right: 1%;">
    <label class="adm">Created</label>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; padding-right: 1%;">
    <label class="adm">Created</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfloat"></div>
<div class="mdl_ftr"></div>
```

And simply apply the CSS rule to this element like

```
.clearfloat { clear: both; }
```

Comment: Are you saying that the part of my CSS  with .clearfix:after{
  clear: both ..   would not work here?

Comment: @ucc no need to add one extra <div class="clearfloat"></div> its increasing dom element count, just add in your css .clearfix{height:10px;}

Comment: Clearing `div` = fail. Better set `clear` on the footer itself.

Comment: @amolv, presuming that you know the floating element's height, setting an height to it would be a better choice. However, for floating elements with dynamic/variable height, this would not be sufficient. And throwing a few if these does really not make an impact on the DOM tree (unless you have many floating elements, but then this is simply abusing the floating CSS rule...). @Midas, perhaps you are right, but I have found some situations where what you're saying didn't work, and adding an extra div like that did. ...and what you consider *bad* may not be a fail, especially when it works.

Answer (score 1):

Please never forget `overflow:hidden` again!!

Replace your full CSS with:

```
.clearfix {
    overflow:hidden
}
.mdl_ftr {
    background:red;
    min-height:45px
}
```

---

Or even better in this case:

**HTML:**

```
<div style="float:left; padding-right:1%">
    <label class="adm">Created</label>
</div>
<div style="float:left; padding-right:1%">
    <label class="adm">Created</label>
</div>

<div class="mdl_ftr"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mdl_ftr {
    background:red;
    min-height:45px;
    clear:both
}
```

And perhaps use an ID for your footer instead of a class. (I guess you have only one footer on your page?)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean after as in to the right of the labels, then put your `mdl_ftr` inside of your `clearfix` and `float:left;`; otherwise, set a height to your `clearfix`

Comment: I'd like the mdl_ftr to appear below. In other words the two labels to appear on one line and then the mdl_ftr area to be below that.

Answer (score 0):

Yea its pretty easy. i put a div.clear at the 
end of your div.clearfix. And added this to your 
css code. **.clear { clear: both; height: 1%; }**

```
<div class="clearfix">
<div style="float: left; padding-right: 1%;">
<label class="adm">Created</label>
</div>
<div style="float: left; padding-right: 1%;">
<label class="adm">Created</label>
</div>
           <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="mdl_ftr"></div>
```